# Multiple Columns in Crystal Sub Report - split by group

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to do the below in Crystal Reports, using version XI.
[Table with two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIaVL.png)

The report is populated from a table containing the Date, A decimal, and a Group number(I was using this to split the Jan-Jun, group 1, and Jul-Dec, group number 2)

I have tried in the Section Expert. Checking the "Format with Multiple Columns"
then Layout>Check "Format Groups with multiple columns".

How would I get crystal to split the columns by first half of year,group 1, and second half of year, group 2, as it shows in the image. It just won't split it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to take 6 sections and create 13 formulas. Then place them manually in a grid formation as per your requirement. Since there are only ever 12 months they can be static objects.

In addition, if you want to set this up for every year, you can add a group by year encompassing the sections

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your report, change your datasource just for this situation. Assume your details section looks like this:

```
month        |        value
-----------------------------
01 January   |        1.5
01 February  |        1.2
01 March     |        1.6
....
```

The simple solution without using lots of sections/formulas is to change your datasource to look like:

```
month1       |        value1       |    month2     |    value2
---------------------------------------------------------------
01 January   |        1.5          | 01 July       |      1.9
01 February  |        1.2          | 01 August     |      1.4
01 March     |        1.6          |               |
....
```

Put those 4 columns into the details section and you're done. Maybe not the best solution, but definitely a different approach that doesn't rely on hardcore formulas and sections.